# How can I get the value of an observable when it changes?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Here's my code:

Dart:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('my-thing')
class MyThing extends PolymerElement {
  @observable var val = "Hello, World";

  MyThing.created() : super.created() {}
}
```

Html:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-thing">
  <template>
    <textarea id="asdf" value="{{val}}"></textarea>
    <p>Val is: {{val}}</p>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_thing.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

You can see that `val` represents the value of a textarea. What I would like to do is this: when the value of the textarea changes, take the last word inside of it, modify it, and update the textarea with the new text.

For example, if the user types "Hello, world", I might want to recognize the word "world" and replace it with an all caps version, "WORLD".

Do I have to use `querySelector` to observe the field, separately from my `@observable` line? I tried this and it did not work:

```dart
querySelector('#inputName').onInput.listen(someUpdate);

void someUpdate(Event e) {
  print('changed');
}
```

I tried it in the `MyThing` class, I tried it in main, and I tried it outside of anything, and none worked.

I feel like there should be some kind of event I can listen for, setup by using `@observable`. Is there? If there's nothing I can listen for or no sort of automatic callbacks I can add, how can I change my `querySelector` line to actually work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is something special with `textarea` but I guess it should fulfill your needs to just add a `valChanged` method to your `MyThing` class. This method is called every time `val` changes.
If you change `val` inside `valChanged` you might run into an endless loop though.

```dart
valChanged(oldValue, newValue) {
  // do stuff here
}
```

or you can use the `change` event

```dart
<textarea id="asdf" value="{{val}}" on-change="{{valChangeHandler}}"></textarea>

valChangeHandler(Event e) {
  // here you get the element passed as `e.target`
  // and you can access `val`
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get a reference to the element whose value changed as well?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe the `change` event is more appropriate for your use case. I updated my answer.